# Wifi randomly restarts, disconnects and gets reconnected automatically

Tags: wifi, parrotsec

Wifi randomly restarts, disconnects and gets reconnected automatically.
How can I solve this issue? I'm using
Parrot OS 5.0 (LTS) (a debian bullseye derivative).

This file is set to 2 `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf`

```
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 2
```

lspci -v

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
        Subsystem: AzureWave RTL8822CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 79, IOMMU group 11
        I/O ports at d000 [size=256]
        Memory at fc800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
        Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
        Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
        Capabilities: [148] Device Serial Number 00-e0-4c-ff-fe-c8-22-01
        Capabilities: [158] Latency Tolerance Reporting
        Capabilities: [160] L1 PM Substates
        Kernel driver in use: rtw_8822ce
        Kernel modules: wl, rtw_8822ce, rtl88x2ce
```

Comment: What's your wifi hardware? A **lot** of wifi chipset firmware is *very* buggy, sadly, and the combination with often not very lovingly tested kernel drivers, that leads to random firmware resets :/

Comment: removing the [tag:arch-linux] tag. You're not using Arch linux. Why did you tag this question as about Arch Linux? That's very confusing.